# Google Password not able to reset

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, service-accounts, user-accounts, reset-password

I am not able to reset my google account password. As it is asking for INSER USB device.
I didn't change my password, even though it is asking. Please help me out to get my google account back. I have YouTube channel also from this account.
LUCKY.OPENER@GMAIL.COM
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FJfc.png)
Please see the image.

I tried to change password through forgot password. But it is not asking for mobile number through which I created the account.